# One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid. in unlock login.keychain

Tags: ios, jenkins

I can't use jenkins to excuse

```
security unlock-keychain -p my password /Users/huizhaofang123/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

the error is :

> password to unlock /Users/huizhaofang123/Library/Keychains/login.keychain:
>
> security: SecKeychainUnlock /Users/huizhaofang123/Library/Keychains/login.keychain: One or more
>   parameters passed to a function were not valid.

plz help! thanks

Comment: if your password really is two words (e.g. `my password`, with a space between the words), then it needs to be put into quotes (e.g. `"my password"`) to make the shell realize it's one parameter and not two parameters

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough, like Michael said wrap your password in quotes or escape the space like this:

```
security unlock-keychain -p my\ password /Users/huizhaofang123/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```